# is it okay to sacrifice const-correctness for speed?

Tags: c++, oop, optimization, constants

I have a factory class that will be used to create a whole lot of instances of a certain class. The creation process is pretty obfuscated and might require a quite a while. So I was thinking it would be smart to store the instances of the class which have already been created inside the factory, I can recall them at a later time.

The creation depends on a single parameter (the name) so things can be stored in a `std::map` which I call `old_instances`.

```
A A_factory::make_A(std::string const& name)
{
    if ( old_instances.find(name) != old_instances.end() )
    {
        return old_instances.find(name) -> second;
    }
    else
    {
        // obfuscated creation process that creates instance 'new_A'
        // ...

        old_instances.insert(std::pair<std::string, A>(name, new_A)); // <- problem
        return new_A;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that this whole routine could be a `const` member of the factory. But because the `old_instances` is adapted.

I kinda feel awkward sacrificing the `const`-ness of a function for something this trivial.
Are these kind of sacrifices logical?

please do not shoot me if this question is too dependent on taste.

Comment: It looks like you are reinventing custom allocators or pooled storage. See e.g. Boost Pool

Comment: That's called **lazy loading** by the way, and is another design pattern often associated with the factory patterns.

Comment: If you are worrying about *such* things, you better worry about the unnecessary copy in your `insert` first!

Comment: @Kerrek SB: enlighten me, what is a quicker way?

Comment: @romeovs: Get the value type of the map right! If you don't know it, use the `value_type` member typedef. If you have C++11, prefer the `emplace` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the classic example of using `mutable`. You should be fine doing this as long as the external behavior truly is that of const.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you - if you think the state of old_instances does not make any observable/conceptual difference to client code of your class then you can make it mutable, and make the factory function const. But you should really make sure it's true, otherwise you will only confuse yourself or others reading your code later on.